# Angular CLI enum creation error

Tags: angular, enums, angular-cli, angular2-cli

When trying to create a enum with the Angular CLI, I get the following error:

```
C:\angular\myapp\src\app\enums>ng generate enum myEnum
installing enum
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.getAppFromConfig (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\app-utils.js:4:19)
    at Class.normalizeEntityName (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\blueprints\enum\index.js:18:39)
    at Class.Blueprint._normalizeEntityName (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\blueprint.js:454:24)
    at Class.Blueprint.install (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\blueprint.js:513:8)
    at Class.run (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\tasks\generate-from-blueprint.js:59:49)
    at Class.run (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\commands\generate.js:71:17)
    at Class.<anonymous> (C:\angular\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:134:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Does someone know if this is a bug on Angular CLI or am I creating enums incorrectly?

I am currently working on Angular CLI version : 1.0.0-rc.0

Comment: Have you performed a clean reinstall/install of *global* and *project local* `angular-cli`? Also nuking the `node_modules/` might help in cases as this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems just upgrading the CLI version did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

I managed to fix the issue... 
Just upgrade to RC.1
and voila! it works!

So i`m not sure if it was a bug on RC.0 or something, but at least its working now...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today too when I tried to run the Angular Quickstart zip package.  If you debug that `app-utils.js` in that error you posted you can see the error. I opened that file in a text editor and did a console.log above that line in the error.  That line is trying to load `angular-cli.json` file and that file was missing in my case (from the quickstart zip file).

Make a new `angular-cli.json` file in that directory you're running this command in (in my case, it was the root) and use the content in my demo repo below.  Then run the `ng generate ...` command again. That worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Note that my `angular-cli.json` is using polyfill.ts, and tsconfig.app.json (anyhow everything is there)

https://github.com/zagros/stack-overflow_angular-cli-enum-creation-error

If you're after i18n support, this may also interest you. The only problem i'm having right now is that `node_modules\.bin\ng-xi18n -p src\tsconfig.json` command needs the template URL's be relative to the TS file, while the `ng start` needs them to start with `app\name.of.template.html`.  So I manually change the paths using an external script I wrote for the time-being, generate my XLIFF files, then change the paths back.  If you're not using XLIFF i18n ignore this bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems just upgrading the CLI version did the trick.